# How would you translate this idiomatic phrase?

Tags: idioms

Italian: *riprendere in mano*

It means continue to work on something you abandoned for some long time (i.e. a couple of months).

Comment: "Restart the project" could work. Lately, I also see people use the phrase "reboot the project" too.

Comment: @DamkerngT. sorry I mean not to start again from scratch, but to continue

Comment: @Sam - [_restart_](https://www.wordnik.com/words/restart) doesn't necessarily mean "start again from scratch." It can also mean "to start again after a pause."

Comment: “I'm going to take [project] up again” is good as well.

Comment: "return to [project]" suggests more of a gap than "restart" I think. Restart *could* mean a gap, but it could also mean you were working on it yesterday, put all your equipment away then got it all out again today.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If a single word would do, then *restart* would work.

If you're looking for a more idiomatic phrase, there's:

> **pick up where we left off**

(the pronoun *we* can be changed to *you* or *I*, depending on who is reinitiating the work, as in: *I haven't been working on my book for awhile; I'm just going to **pick up where I left off***.)

Macmillan mentions this phrase specifically, under its entry for *pick up*:

> **pick up** `11` to start something again, from the point where you stopped : *We'll pick up this conversation later*.
>   **pick up where you left off**: *He seems to think that we can get back together and just pick up where we left off*.

The phrase implies that you won't need to do a lot of backtracking, so it may not be appropriate if you'll need to take a few steps backward in order to proceed.

Answer (score 3):

[*Resurrect the project*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=resurrect+project&t=crmtb01) is often used.

It indicates that a dead project has been brought back to life.